# docker-compose "depends_on", but with "docker run"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-run

How can I implement the below `docker-compose` code, but using the `docker run` command? I am specifically interested in the `depends_on` part.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`depends_on:` doesn't map to a `docker run` option.  When you have your two `docker run` commands you need to make sure you put them in the right order.

```bash
docker build -t web_image .
docker network create some_network
docker run --name db --net some_network postgres
# because this depends_on: [db] it must be second
docker run --name web --net some_network ... web_image ...
```

Comment: Thanks - however it's possible that the DB is not ready to connect to when the web container wants to connect to it. Do you have any suggestion for such a scenario?

Comment: Compose `depends_on:` doesn't help that case at all.  [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) has some more discussion of this.  In this particular context, any of the setups that involve a `wait-for.sh` script could be run from the host to delay creating the second container until the first one is ready.

Comment: (The standard Kubernetes approach is for the database client to just crash and restart; in your context, `docker run --restart=on-failure`.)

Answer (score 0):

depends-on mean :

Compose implementations MUST guarantee dependency services have been started before starting a dependent service. Compose implementations MAY wait for dependency services to be “ready” before starting a dependent service.

Hence the depends on is not only an order of running
and you can use docker-compose instead of docker run and every option in docker run can be in the docker-compose file